# Are there any open source java libraries which can resize as well as enhance any type of images?

Tags: java, image-processing

Are there any opnesource java libraries which can **resize** as well as **enhance** any type of images(jpg, jpeg, png, PNG to be precise)?

Comment: Guys you all are talking about resize how about enhance image?

Comment: What do you specifically mean by 'enhance' ? This should get you started on that - http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai1_0_1guide-unc/Image-enhance.doc.html   and http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai1_0_1guide-unc/

Answer (score 1):

For re-sizing the image you can use the Java library javax.imageio

Sample code is as

```
BufferedImage createResizedCopy(Image originalImage,  
        int scaledWidth, int scaledHeight,  
        boolean preserveAlpha) 
{ 
    System.out.println("resizing..."); 
    int imageType = preserveAlpha ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB : BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB; 
    BufferedImage scaledBI = new BufferedImage(scaledWidth, scaledHeight, imageType); 
    Graphics2D g = scaledBI.createGraphics(); 
    if (preserveAlpha) { 
        g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src); 
    } 
    g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, null);  
    g.dispose(); 
    return scaledBI; 
}
```

A sample running app using this function is [Example for image re-sizing using Java](http://warm-sunrise-5783.herokuapp.com/?url=http://i.imgur.com/By9gL.jpg&height=400&width=400)

You can pass any image URL as a ?url and ?height , ?width.

Answer (score 0):

What about http://www.jmagick.org ?

Answer (score 0):

Check Scalr:

http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/

Easy to resize an image:

```
Scalr.resize(img, maxWidth, maxHeight, (BufferedImageOp) null);
```